# How to consider different size of input for "Graph Conv Network"

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm a student who just start study deep learning.

I hope to practice with simple project using Graph Convolution Network.

The question is that "How can I handle with different size of input graph for GCN?"

Padding with zero is the only way to handle this problem? And zero padding like CNN is proper also for GCN?

Thanks

Comment: I hope to study about molecule or protein with graph convolutional network!

Comment: Zero-padding is the most common way. You might find a good approach in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.03965.pdf which is designed for large-scale cases

Comment: Thanks for suggestion!